# how to add command line calculator to bash that uses comma as decimal mark?

Tags: awk, bashrc, bc, calculator

How can I add a command line calculator to my bash? I have found some, but all of them use the [full stop as decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_point), but I want to have it to use the **[comma as decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma)** as most of the world does, see picture:

[image: map of the world showing the use of decimal marks]

(source wikipedia)

- blue: Full stop/Period (.)
- green: Comma (,)
- red: Momayyez (٫)
- gray: Data unavailable

---

The ones that I have found (all with full stop as decimal mark) are the following, where these lines have to be put into your `~/.bashrc` file:

1. Using bc, which has the advantage, that you can calculate ridiculously large numbers:

   ```
   calc () {
     bc -l <<< "$@"
   }
   ```
2. With awk, where you have mnemonic names for trigonometric and other functions and you can use fractional exponents and you can give the exponent by the two chars `**` instead of the, on some keyboards difficult to type `^`:

   ```
   calc () {
     awk "BEGIN { print $* ; }"
   }
   ```

Comment: I doubt it's _most_ if it includes none of India, China or the USA (those 3 account for 40% of the world population)

Comment: Well, if you say China, India and USA (and I say Egypt) have 40% of the world’s population, and knowing that Australia and the few remaining blue countries in Africa are close to empty, the rest (60%) uses the comma as decimal mark. q.e.d.

Comment: Pakistan, Philippines, Nigeria, Japan, Mexico are [another 10%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population).

Comment: Note that `,` also doubles as an operator in many arithmetic expressions (C, shell, perl...). `ksh93`, which honours the locale's decimal_point has that issue. `LC_ALL=fr_FR ksh93 -c 'echo $((1,2))'` outputs `1,2` and `2` in an English locale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
calc () {
  awk '
    function asin(x) { return atan2(x, sqrt(1-x*x)) }
    function acos(x) { return atan2(sqrt(1-x*x), x) }
    function atan(x) { return atan2(x,1) }
    function tan(x) { return sin(x)/cos(x) }
    BEGIN { pi=atan(1)*4; print '"$(echo "$@" | tr , .)}" | tr . ,
}
```

This one

- accepts numbers as 5,2 or 5.2 (i.e. both full stop and comma as decimal mark)
- it uses comma as decimal mark for the output/solution
- spaces and tabs are removed from input, i.e. you can enter easy readable calculations as input
- the number pi is defined via 4*atan(1)
- some common trigonometric functions are defined

Answer (score 4):

There is no reliable way to implement that. The issue is the comma is used to separate arguments when more that one is passed to a function.

If you aren't going to use such functions, I guess the simplest way would be something like:

```
calc () {
  echo "scale=6;" "$@" | tr , . | bc -l | tr . ,
}
```

That gives:

```
$ calc 1 + 1
2
$ calc 1 / 3
,333333
$ calc "s(0,5)^2"   # sin(0.5)^2
,229848
$ calc "4*a(1)"     # PI
3,141592
```

You can of course increase the decimal precision which is here 6 digits.

Comment: Nice. Easier to understand than the nested awk statement. But I miss calculations like `27^(1/3)` and the (for me) easier to type `27**(1/3)` which awk supports.